# Is this integral unfit for partial fraction decomposition?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, partial-fractions

I've been tasked with computing the following integral:

$$\int_0^4\frac{x^3+10x^2+3x+36}{(x-1)(x^2+4)^2}\text dx$$

The issue I have here is that the numerator is of a higher degree than the denominator; however when consulting some online resources it seems they go ahead with the decomposition anyway.

Is the degree of the polynomial on the denominator taken when it's fully expanded out (i.e, for this question, $x^5 - x^4 + 8x^3 - 8x^2 + 16x - 16$) (And a factored form can actually be of a lesser degree) or are these calculators doing something I'm not aware of?

Just really confused as to this.

Comment: There's no problem: Like you say, the degree of the numerator ($3$) is less than the degree of the denominator ($5$), so we can proceed with the Method of Partial Fractions immediately.

Comment: Right, so the degree is based off the expanded polynomial, not the factored version, thank you!

Comment: The integral diverges. Is the task to compute the Cauchy Principal Value?

Comment: It was simply tasked to compute the area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make the Ansatz
$$\frac{x^3+10x^2+3x+36}{(x-1)(x^2+4)^2}=\frac{A}{x-1}+\frac{Bx+C}{x^2+4}+\frac{Dx+E}{(x^2+4)^2}$$

Comment: What do you mean by Ansatz?

Comment: Ansatz is also an english word and mean Approach or so

Comment: I have never come across it in English, but OK

Comment: should i search in a dictionary for you?

Comment: @lioness99a Here is a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansatz) on it.

Comment: oh nice thank you for the link

Answer (score 0):

The integrand can be split as $$\frac{2}{x - 1} + \frac{x}{ \left(x^{2} + 4 \right)^{2}} + \frac{-2 \; x - 1}{x^{2} + 4}$$

Comment: And (as noted) $\int_0^4$ of the first term diverges, but the other terms converge.  So the whole thing diverges.